# Sequent calculus: What does it mean to say “choose the sequents from which we can derive some other sequent via the right conjunction rule”?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

My question is probably quite silly really, but I am puzzled what this exercise is asking:

> **Excercise.** Choose all sequents from which we can derive some other sequent via the right-side conjunction rule.
>
> 1. $\color{green}{\lnot (A\land B), \lnot A \vdash A\land B}$ (correct)
> 2. $\lnot (A\land B), A \vdash A\land B$
> 3. $\color{green}{\lnot (A\land B), \lnot A \vdash \lnot A \land \lnot B}$ (correct)
> 4. $\lnot (A\land B), B \vdash \lnot A \land \lnot B$
> 5. $\lnot (A\land B), \lnot B \vdash A\land B$
>
> (*Source: homework excerise in since-discontinued course, translated*)

The correct answers are marked green.

Here is the referenced

> **Right-side conjunction rule:**
> $$\cfrac{\Gamma \vdash \mathcal{F}\quad \Gamma \vdash \mathcal{G}}{\Gamma\vdash \mathcal{F}\land \mathcal{G}}$$
> where $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ are zeroth order formulae, and $\Gamma$ is a list of zeroth order formulae or is empty.

---

I believe I do understand the basics of Gentzen's sequent calculus. I am aware of the axioms and rules for allowed derivations, including the right-side conjunction rule; the intuition behind the formalisation is also clear. I have derived dozens upon dozens of formulae in sequent calculus (as trees), and proved, for example, the correctness and completeness of sequent calculus wrt tautologies in propositional calculus.

With this in mind,

- the problem is **not** *how* to solve the excercise. Rather, my problem is in understanding *what* is even being asked in the first place. So: What exactly is the excercise after?

Even with the “correct” answers known, I am admittedly confused. Firstly, the multiple choices are all of the form $\Omega \vdash \mathcal{F} \land \mathcal{G}$ (with varying $\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$). One usually uses the right-side conjunction rule to *derive sequents* of the form $\Omega \vdash \mathcal{F} \land \mathcal{G}$, not use them as “sequents from which” to derive other sequents. Secondly, what are the “some other sequents” which I should check? Others from the multiple-choice list? Other sequents in general?

Perhaps the phrasing of the exercise is a bit off from what is common... Is this a common type of exercise, maybe you can recognize the intended idea behind it? To reiterate, what is the exercise asking for?

**EDIT**

Here is another exercise of the same type. I also know the “correct” answer(s) to the test excercise but I will omit this information at first. That way I have an elementary check if an answer has the intended interpretation.

> **Test excercise.**
> Choose all sequents from which we can derive some other sequent via the **left**-side conjunction rule.
>
> 1. $\vdash (X \lor \lnot X) \land (Y \lor \lnot Y)$
> 2. $Z, X \land Y \vdash \lnot X \lor \lnot Y \lor \lnot Z$
> 3. $X \land (Y \lor Z), Y \land (X \lor Z) \vdash X \land Y \land Z$
> 4. $\lnot Z \land \lnot X \vdash (Y \lor \lnot Z) \land (\lnot Y \lor \lnot X)$
> 5. $X\land Y \vdash X\lor Y$
>
> (*Source: homework excerise in since-discontinued course, translated*)

> **Left-side conjunction rule:**
> $$\cfrac{\Gamma, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G} \vdash \mathcal{H}}{\Gamma, \mathcal{F} \land \mathcal{G} \vdash \mathcal{H}}$$
> where $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ are zeroth order formulae, and $\Gamma$ is a list of zeroth order formulae or is empty.

The correct answers were indeed (spoiler)

> 2 and 3.

Comment: If the approach suggested in the answers below is the correct one, you can use only 2 and 3

Comment: If this interpretation is the correct one, the exercises are not about performing derivations, but about understanding the syntax of inference rules (e.g. *shared contexts* for two-premises rules).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for thinking along! Indeed, the correct answers for the test exercise were 2 and 3. As a result of the answers and the question, the exercise probably meant to ask “Which of the following sequents can be used together (paired) in order to derive (infer) *any* well-formed formula (which may or may not be listed as a choice) by the right-side conjunction rule?” (and modified accordingly for the test exercise). This interpretation of the question never occured to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the answer, I think I can figure out what the question was intended to be. An application of the right-$\land$ rule needs two premises, and those two premises must have the same set $\Gamma$ of formulas to the left of $\vdash$. The two green sequents have the same formulas to the left of $\vdash$, and no two others on your list of five options do that.  So the two green sequents, and only those two, can serve as the two premises in an application of right-$\land$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer which does indeed seem to be correct. Glad to see others can, at least given the correct answer, derive the meaning for the question. I would have worded the exercise as “Which of the following sequents can be used together (paired) in order to derive *any* well-formed formula (which may or may not be listed as a choice) by the right-side conjunction rule?“. But with that wording, the exercise is very straightforward, therefore I would not make it an exercise to begin with :=). I will probably accept your answer in 24 to 48 h.

Answer (score 1):

"Firstly, the multiple choices are all of the form Ω⊢F∧G. "

By that sort of reasoning, also, all of the multiple choices are of the form Ω⊢F and Ω⊢G.  Note that every well-formed formula in formal logic has the form of a variable.

But, they are not all of the same form Ω⊢F∧G where Ω indicates a defined list, and they don't all have the same Ω.

"One usually uses the right-side conjunction rule to derive sequents of the form Ω⊢F∧G, not use them as “sequents from which” to derive other sequents."

Consider proving that $\land$ associates .  I believe that if you do so, you'll find using sequents with conjuncitons to derive other conjunctions.

"Secondly, what are the “some other sequents” which I should check?"

What other sequents have the same premises in the same order?

The idea behind the exercise lies in recognizing when premise lists are equivalent as lists and also recognizing that the right-side conjunction rule *requires* that the assumed sequents have equivalent premise lists, otherwise the rule can't get used properly.  Thus, 1. can't get used with 2., 3., nor 5. since the antecedents consist of different lists, nor 4. get used with 5., and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I intended indeed for $\Omega, \mathcal{F} \land \mathcal{G}$ to vary, not be fixed beforehand (made this more explicit in an edit). So, in this case, a rewording of the question would be “Which of the following sequents can be used together (paired) in order to derive *any* well-formed formula (which may or may not be listed as a choice) by the right-side conjunction rule?”.